Flutter how to navigate to a page from the notifications bar
I send users notifications to check their calendar from Firebase messaging. When the user clicks on the notification message I want the app to navigate to the calendar page.
The problem is if they click the message then they have to login first.
Once they login, it goes to the homepage and not the page that I want it to go.
How can that page persist login so that it goes to the calendar screen in my app.
This is where the entry point from Firebase Messaging goes. This is in my Main.Dart
Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    // Get any messages which caused the application to open from
    // a terminated state.
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    // If the message also contains a data property with a "type" of "chat",
    // navigate to a chat screen
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }

    // Also handle any interaction when the app is in the background via a
    // Stream listener
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
  }

  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'calendar') {
      Logger().w('Calendar is selected. Need to Navigate here');
      
    }
  }


I hope I can help you!
you can use NavigatorKey to push page you want.
In the message data you should put the router name of the page you want (example in Compose notification firebase):

and add the code to the handlemessage function:
final route = message.data["route"];
navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(
    route,
    arguments: message
);


Thanks quick question: If I need to Navigate to a tab how would I do that? Also will this method persist the login?
